# Apple Sign In with Flutter and Auth0

Tags: flutter, auth0, apple-sign-in

I have a flutter app and use this package to implement Apple Sign In feature: https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple

I get the authorization data from the Apple like below:

```
userIdentifier = "0XXXX7.6bb65XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX36.1XXX2"
givenName = "test"
familyName = "signing"
email = "testemail@company.com"
authorizationCode = "c372xxxxxxxa526eexxxxxx1111e.0.rwsex.SwXxxXXXdDj_XxxXXXxxX"
identityToken = "eyJraXxxuxjxxxXxxxXx.eyJXxxxxtXxxxxxxhlYXxxXXxXxXXXXX"
state = null
```

Then I tries to send the `authorizationCode` as described here in Step 3: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/nativesocial/apple
And I get the 403 Forbidded `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}`

I have configured the settings in the Auth0 dashobard in Social and Applications section.
The login process works well in the web environment but I can not do it in the Flutter.

Could anyone help me with what should I do with the `authorizationCode` to perform successful login and get Access Token and ID Token from Auth0 in the native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather a late answer, but I've found following [the documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?javascript#token-exchange-for-native-social) for the `/oauth/token` end-point titled "Token Exchange for Native Social" works for me.

Specifically sending that end-point a POST, eg. with this in Dart code:

```dart
    final appleAuthorizationCode = '???????????????????????';
    const url = 'https://$AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token';
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final result = await http.post(
      uri,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: {
        "client_id": AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        "grant_type": 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange',
        "subject_token": appleAuthorizationCode,
        "subject_token_type": 'http://auth0.com/oauth/token-type/apple-authz-code',
        "scope": 'openid profile offline_access',
      },
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    );
    print('AUTH0 result: $result');
```

works for me.